# Unity Validation Help in If's statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So when my the answer is wrong on TextValidation 
for example TextValidation value = "fable" nothing will work and when the TextValidation value is not on "fable" or anything else nothing is happening either. I tried to remove the else on my statement and TextValidation value = "fable" is working again . I don't know what is wrong in my code T_T .

```
public TextMeshProUGUI TextValidation;
string[] rightanswers = { "able", "alef", "bale", "blae", "feal", 
    "flab", "flea", "leaf", "fable" };

public void rightanswersButton()
{
    for (int index = 0; index < rightanswers.Length; index++)
    {
        if (finalAnswer == rightanswers[index])
        {        
            TextValidation.text = "You are correct your answer is :" + finalAnswer;
            delete();
        }
        else
        {
            TextValidation.text = "You are wrong";
            delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Nothing will work" isn't very helpful. Neither is "nothing is happening", although it does tell us more than the first. Either way, you're never checking TextValidation for "fable". You're checking if `finalAnswer` is equal to `rightanswers[index]` and we can't see what `finalAnswer` is.

Comment: sorry didn't include that the finalAnswer depends on the user input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only concerned with whether the user's value is present in the array, but you're checking every value so you're going to end up finding at most one right answer and a whole bunch of wrong answers, and printing out tons of unnecessary messages.

There's a few ways to attack this. For instance, if you find a value then you could set a flag and break out of the loop early.

```
bool isFound = false;
for (int index = 0; index < rightanswers.Length; index++)
{
    if (finalAnswer == rightanswers[index])
    {        
        isFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (isFound)
    TextValidation.text = "You are correct your answer is :" + finalAnswer;
else
    TextValidation.text = "You are wrong";
delete();
```

Alternatively, you could use LINQ to find out if any of the elements in the array match the value you're looking for.

```
if (rightanswers.Any(x => x == finalAnswer))
    TextValidation.text = "You are correct your answer is :" + finalAnswer;
else
    TextValidation.text = "You are wrong";
delete();
```

Comment: tbh it looks like this is a homework question, which means use of built-in methods like LINQ might not be desirable if the objective is to become familiar with the usage of arrays.

Comment: nope , I've been making a game sorry . I'm just learning only the basics of unity and not so familiar with arrays

Comment: oh sorry sir it's working fantastically now!! ps. error is I didnt put my text in the screen I thought it's not working hehe

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer if it worked for you @NicoleErasga so it helps others with a similar problem in the future.